# How could read application.ini on controller using zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, ini

I have these lines in my application.ini

how can I read **user** in my contrroler

```
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.driver   = "pdo_mysql"
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.dbname   = "zc"
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.host = "localhost"
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.port = 3306
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.user = "root"
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.password = "123456"
```

I use of this code but it retuens null

```
$bootstrap = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap');
 $user = $bootstrap->getOption('user');
var_dump($user);
```

**edit:**
how may I read all of **connections** options ?

Comment: I think [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html) should help you.

Comment: Is it solved? And if so, could you please accept the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should use

```
$this->getInvokeArgs('bootstrap');
```

For more info [see this chapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.theory-of-operation.html#zend.application.theory-of-operation.bootstrap.registry) in manual.

What about using

```
$conf = $bootstrap->getOption('resources');
$dbConf = $conf['doctrine']['dbal']['connections']['default']['parameters'];
```

Comment: i think $bootstrap = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');  and $bootstrap = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap'); are same

Comment: Well I'm not sure. One more idea ;)

Comment: But is there a way to get config params not like array elems but oop-style? Like `$a = $conf->one->two`?. Please my question about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887873/how-to-retrieve-parameters-from-zend-application-ini-file-during-the-session

Comment: `$config = new Zend_Config($conf);` or http://www.richardcastera.com/blog/php-convert-array-to-object-with-stdclass

Answer (score 3):

How about something like:

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini', APPLICATION_ENV);
$connectionParams = $config->resources->doctrine->connections;
```

Or during `Bootstrap`, create and save this `$config` object in the `Bootstrap` or in the `Zend_Registry` for later retrieval in your controller.

Comment: I think its not a good idea. You make system to read your application.ini twice. And then its uncomfortable to retrieve parameters from config with Zend_Registry. Please see my question on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887873/how-to-retrieve-parameters-from-zend-application-ini-file-during-the-session

Comment: Of course, you're right: he should not be reading/loading/parsing the .ini file twice. The important part is how to drill down into the config object/array to get at the data he needs. Thanks! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This goes in your controller.

```
$bootstrap = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
$appinidata = $bootstrap->getOptions();
$user=$appinidata['resources']['doctrine']['dbal']['connections']['default']['parameters'] ['user'];
```

This should print "root".

```
print_r($user);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get to the Doctrine container resource, just use :

```
$bootstrap = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
$doctrine = $bootstrap->getResource('doctrine');
```

From there you can drill down to the user name of the default connection (you can specify the connection if needed, just pass the name of the connection in the call to getConnection) :

```
$username = $doctrine->getConnection()->getUsername();
```

Comment: $username = $doctrine->getConnection()->getUsername(); does returen "root" in my example ?

Comment: Yeah, it should return **root** when used with your application.ini.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use  **Zend_Config_Ini** class

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini('/path/to/config.ini','staging',$options);
```

*second parameter* is a section in **INI** file  should be loaded ;
*third parameter* is the key to allow modify loaded file.

You can put out value **user** this way:

```
$config->resources->doctrine->dbal->connections->default->parameters->user;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set any variable using set method as following on index.php inside the public folder
Let

$config = 'test';
**Zend_Registry::set('config', $config);**

once the variable has been set then you can get on any controllers/models by following method

**Zend_Registry::get('config');**

Hop it Helps!!