# How to retrieve parameters from Zend application.ini file during the session?

Tags: zend-framework, configuration, zend-config, zend-app-bootstrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How could read application.ini on controller using zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699844/how-could-read-application-ini-on-controller-using-zend-framework)

`application.ini` is a configuration file in ZF. I have there some more settings than just those defaults that ZF manual writes about. But how may I retrieve those parameters from it from my action controllers for example? And where is it better to store this config during the session?

The `Bootstrap_Abstract` class has `getOptions()` method which returns a simple php array of read `application.ini` file:

```
$app = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, '/application.ini');
$config = $app->bootstrap()->getOptions();  // $config is a php array of application.ini
```

And I'd like to get element form it oop-style:

```
$param = $config[one][two];  // vs.
$param = $config->one->two;  // like this
```

ZF has `Zend_Config_Ini` class which reads `.ini`'s and returns exactly the ArrayObject. But I'd like to avoid reading `application.ini` with `Zend_Config_Ini` one more time after `Zend_Application` has anyway already read it. But `Bootstrap` or `Zend_Application` classes don't provide some automatic creation of ArrayObject from `application.ini`.

And the second, where may I store this $config then? In `Zend_Registry`?

```
Zend_Registry::set('config', $config);
```

And then in my some action controller I retrieve it:

```
$config = Zend_Registry::get('config');  // I retrieve config
$param = $config->one->two;              // I retrieve parameter from it and use it
```

But it seems a little inefficient: I have one copy of `application.ini` in the `Bootstrap` in the form of usual php array and one copy of the same `application.ini` but in the form of ArrayObject in `Zend_Registry` too. And have to make two steps to get a parameter from my config. How can I solve this problem more efficiently?

Comment: See also http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/accessing-your-configuration-data-in-application-ini/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using `Zend_Controller_Front`, you can retrieve information from `application.ini` from anywhere in your application (controller, plugin, models etc) using code like this:

```
$config = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap');
```

Say in `application.ini` you had some options like this:

```
apikeys.google.maps.id  = "abc"
apikeys.google.maps.key = "123456789"
apikeys.twitter.oauth   = "20jg9032jg9320gj30"
```

You can then access those values using the above `$config` variable:

```
$apikeys = $config->getOption('apikeys');
$mapsId  = $apikeys['google']['maps']['id'];  // abc
$maksKey = $apikeys['google']['maps']['key']; // 123456789
$twitKey = $apikeys['twitter']['oauth'];      // 20jg9032jg9320gj30
```

Hope that helps.